# Как использовать нужный id?

Tags: java, android, youtube

Есть пару картинок с ссылками, хочу чтоб по нажатию на них открывалось конкретное видео.

Обрабатываю нажатие следующим образом

```
viewHolder.photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String id = "";
                    Intent appIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:" + id));
                    Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + id));
                    try {
                        context.startActivity(appIntent);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                        context.startActivity(webIntent);
                    }
```

Только тут всё дело в id как мне кажется... как возможно вытащить по нажатию корректно если ссылки каждый раз разные? Нужно использовать для нескольких видео, а не для одной ссылки.

код адаптера

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    List<ImageUpload> imageUploads;
    int resource;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<ImageUpload> imageUploads, int resource) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imageUploads = imageUploads;
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final GridHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new GridHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater1 = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            if (imageUploads.get(position).getOutputMetadata().getFilename().equals("null")) {
                convertView = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.item_upload_default, parent, false);
            } else {
                convertView = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.item_upload, parent, false);
            }
            viewHolder.photo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_upload);
            viewHolder.closeView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo_close_btn);
            viewHolder.progress = (ProgressWheel) convertView.findViewById(R.id.loader_photo);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (GridHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        if (imageUploads.get(position).getOutputMetadata().getFilename().equals("null")) {
            viewHolder.photo.setImageResource(resource);
        } else {
            ImageUpload mobile = imageUploads.get(position);
            if (imageUploads.get(position).isLoadImage())
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mobile.getOutputMetadata().getVideoUrl()))
                    Picasso.with(context)
                            .load(StringUtil.URLADS_THUMBLER_RESIZE + 150 + "x" + 150 + "/" + StringUtil.URLADS_THUMBLER_IMAGE + mobile.getOutputMetadata().getFilename())
                            .into(viewHolder.photo, new Callback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess() {
                                    viewHolder.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError() {

                                }
                            });
                else {
                    Picasso.with(context).load(mobile.getOutputMetadata().getVideoUrl()).into(viewHolder.photo);
                    viewHolder.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            else {
                File f = new File(imageUploads.get(position).getPath());
                Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(f)
                        .into(viewHolder.photo);
            }

            viewHolder.closeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ((GridView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0);
                }
            });

            viewHolder.photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String id = "";
                    String expression = "";
                    if (id != null && id.trim().length() > 0 && id.matches(".*\\byoutube\\b.*")) {
                        expression = "^.*((youtu.be" + "\\/)" + "|(v\\/)|(\\/u\\/w\\/)|(embed\\/)|(watch\\?))\\??v?=?([^#\\&\\?]*).*";
                        Intent appIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:" + id));
                        Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + id));
                        try {
                            context.startActivity(appIntent);
                        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                            context.startActivity(webIntent);
                        }
                    }

                );
            }
            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: Код всего адаптера покажите.

Comment: @post_zeew обновил вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ImageUpload currentImageUpload = imageUploads.get(position);
```

Здесь `currentImageUpload` – это выбранный элемент. Далее согласно структуре `ImageUpload` можете получить содержимое ее конкретного элемента.

---

**UPD**.

```
viewHolder.photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String id = imageUploads.get(position).getId();
        Intent appIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:" + id));
        Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + id));
        try {
            context.startActivity(appIntent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            context.startActivity(webIntent);
        }
        }
    }
```

Здесь нужно заменить метод `getId()` на тот метод, который возвращает `Id` Вашего объекта типа `ImageUpload`.

Comment: Спасибо, но всё равно не оч понятно, как его можно использовать в методе onClick по "выбранному элементу". А именно получать содержимое из элемента.

Comment: Добавьте код класса `ImageUpload` и укажите, что в нем есть «ссылка», которую Вы хотите открыть.

Comment: подчеркивает position...

Comment: И что говорит? Ну Вы, я надеюсь, этот `position` хотите использовать там где он объявлен, да? Где?

Comment: в метод getView, вставил всё работает норм. А где теперь можно указать что в нём есть ссылка которую я хочу открыть?

Comment: Смотрите **UPD**.

Comment: спасибо за ответы, но что то всё равно не отрабатывает как надо, уже буду переписывать.

Comment: кстати может вы лучше сориентируетесь в этом коде , в ImageUpload mobile = imageUploads.get(position); я сохраняю картинку и потом её использую, или я не совсем правильно разобрался в коде?

Comment: В строке `ImageUpload mobile = imageUploads.get(position);` переменной `mobile` присваивается ссылка на элемент списка `imageUploads`, который находится на позиции `position`. Про сохранение картинок здесь речи нет.

Comment: где же тогда тут сохраняется картинка? потому что она 100% сохраняется. Дело в том что я хочу также потом попробовать сохранить ссылку(есть вероятность что это не тут, но не спросить я не могу)

Comment: Если бы я еще понимал, что здесь есть «картинка» и куда именно она должна сохраняться.

Comment: извините за 1000-ый вопрос, но вот здесь видимо я добавляю картинку, и сюда же хочу добавить url
controlList.get(position).getImageUploads().add(0,imageUpload);
но просто дописать атрибут не выходит(
Хотя в методе, где он прописан вроде как все корректно  void userInput(String url, int position) {

Comment: Я ничего не понял.